# Android / Java Create SOAP envelop

Tags: java, soap

I have a .NET server configured to receive soap 1.2 envelop with WSHTTPBinding .

I want to send a SOAP request to the server from my client app running on Android device .

I don't know whether the request needs to send a X509 certificate or its components like IssuerDN . serial number etc .

I have found following link :
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/distributedservices/archive/2010/06/14/wcf-interoperability-guidelines-1-reference-style-of-a-primary-signing-token-inside-a-response.aspx

which gives envelop structure for SOAP response but I want the structure for request part.

I have a valid certificate in .p12 format containing

1) private key

2) CA certificate

3) Client certificate

I want to use this certificate for client Authentication .

Comment: I recommend using a library like ksoap2 for SOAP on Android. There you'll probably find more info on authenication, too.

Comment: Hi , Ksoap2 has methods to create a SOAP envelop . It requires the name attributes and token names to be available beforehand . As in my case I don't know the proper token formats and names to make the envelop .Is it like that the envelop needs a specific format only ??

Comment: Well, you need to have some kind of interface, don't you?

Comment: Hi Fildor , thanks for your comments . I am not much experienced on android and java. While searching on internet I came across various interfaces (such as SOAPbody) which comes with SAAJ API . With reference to the MSDN link in original post , I think there must be some predefined tokes which acts as ordered nodes of the SOAP envelop.

Comment: But what you actually want to do is RMI through SOAP, right? So for all I know, you shouldn't be all too concerned with envelopes since the Libraries should handle most of that stuff for you.

Comment: @ Fildor : yes it will be similar to RMI using SOAP . So do you have any idea of what libraries can be put in use for my application. My idea is that there must be some direct API where we could pass our certificate and it will return the respective SOAP header .

Comment: I'll ask a colleague of mine since this is not exactly my field of operation. I was pretty sure that all this should be possible with ksoap. But it is possible, that I am wrong. It has been a while ...

Comment: @ Fildor :  thank you for taking time , awaiting your comments .